# Error codes + error descriptions

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following classes in my project:

- Car
- Truck
- Bicycle
- Plane

User initializes each class with input. For example, for Car, they initialize with model, make, etc.

I have validation functions that use key value validation to validate all of the properties in each model.

Then, for each validate function, I set the NSError input parameter for that function.

The problem is I have over 20 error codes matching to over 20 error descriptions. For example, if the user did not put a valid Car Model, they get an error code 1000 with error description, "Please input valid car model." Right now, I use a long switch statement inside a function in the parent class of all of these models to match each error code to an error description and create the appropriate nserror object for each sub class validation function. Is there a better and more manageable way to handle the mapping of over 20 error codes to error descriptions?

Also, another question, how specific should an error code be? For example, if car model is nil or car model is not a valid model (not nil, just not valid), should there be a difference in error code between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand your situation, but you should be adding the error description to the at the same time you add the error code, i.e. when you create the `NSError` object.

`[NSError errorWithDomain:@"aDomain" code:1 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: @"Please input valid car model."}];`

Then when you need to present the error to the user, just grab the description from the error:

`NSString *errorText = error.userInfo[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary. Convert the error codes into `NSNumber` instances and set the associated values to the error descriptions. Then, when you create the error just get the description from the dictionary.

Comment: How can I define and declare an nsdictionary as a external variable in another class so that it could be used in many classes?

Comment: You could have a class with a public class method which returns the dictionary. Internally that method checks if the dict is loaded (stored in a static variable), loads if not and returns it.